# how I could paint a line in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have this image and I trying to paint the third line from left
and fourth  line for up

[image]

for output this

[image]

[image]

how I could do this ;please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less like this - you can do the exact numbers :-)

```
convert frame.png -fill red -draw "line 305,80 1180,80" -draw "line 305,80 305,435" result.png
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What happens for example is that I have an image that captures a box and that box does not always have the same area

Comment: i refer in this image how i can find the nearest linee from top

Comment: this image has the same area but sometimes i screenshot a image and does have the same area